# Transparent backgroundColor for an Image using React Native on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have an asset with transparent background being used on our app. While on iOS, setting `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` for the Image component works as expected, on Android, it always gets rendered with a light grey background.

In fact, backgroundColor value seems to be completely ignored on Android.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

```
<View style={styles.cardHeader}>
  <Image
    source={require('../assets/images/greeting.png')}
    style={styles.greetingImage} />
</View>
```

*Styles*:

```
cardHeader: {
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: Color.GREY,
  paddingTop: 30,
  borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
  borderTopRightRadius: 5
},

greetingImage: {
  alignSelf: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using rgba, instead of 'transparent'?

Comment: Yes, @TaylorKing! Unfortunately, no luck. Property backgroundColor seems to be ignored on Android.

Comment: Hmmm, it might help to know what you are trying to achieve exactly ... what are the styles for the cardHeader as well?

Comment: Thanks, @TaylorKing! I've updated my question with more details. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realised that I was importing my `Image` component from [shoutem-ui](https://shoutem.github.io/ui/) instead of `react-native`. This is why I was not being able to set a background color, which seems to be ignored by the former, but not the later.

If you stumble on something similar, be sure you're importing the componentes from the right package:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I had a problem when switching from screen to a screen. The image in the header was reloading and I could see the grey background. The image component was from 'react-native-elements'. The above change fixed the problem. Thanks @Diego

Comment: Your answer made me realize that in my case - the "grey background" was part of the image I was displaying! -- so it would be a good idea to qa with **multiple & different images**

Answer (score 2):

You can also add StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject to your container.

```css
greetingImage: {
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  alignSelf: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```